# MySQL MATCH AGAINST when searching e-mail addresses

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I am writing a newsletter script and I need to implement searching in the addresses. I indexed the table with FULLTEXT but when I do a query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE MATCH(email) AGAINST("name@example.com" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I get strange results. It displays all emails on "example.com" and all emails with user "name". For example I get:

```
john@example.com
name@mail.net
steven@example.com
```

I rewrote the query to use LIKE "%name@example.com%" but for a big table it takes ridiculous amount of time to complete.
Is there a solution for this? I want when searching to show only full matching emails and not part of them. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you want an exact match to a column then why can't you just `SELECT * FROM Addresses WHERE email = "name@example.com"`?

Comment: Because on an 7M records table it takes 5 seconds to find it. With MATCH AGAINST it's a lot faster.

Comment: Give the email column a normal index to make the straight comparison query fast. There is no benefit in a fulltext index here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To match an exact phrase you have to enclose the phrase in double quotes. So change your query to:

`SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE MATCH(email) AGAINST('"name@example.com"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

[Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

Comment: I can't believe I didn't thought of that. Thank you, this solved my problem.

Comment: Seriously though, consider a `SELECT` on an indexed column. Should be much faster than a match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a traditional index (with a simple = operator) instead of a fulltext index. It will work fast and use less resource on DB engine.

```
SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE email = 'name@example.com';
```

In this case, it is also possible to use a like operator, with % at the end of search string if you want to find by initial part of email address.

```
SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE email like 'name@exam%';
```