# FULLTEXT search - special characters

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a `companies` table that contains several thousands rows and will grow bigger over time. The requirement is to build a search page that will search in title and description fields that are on that table.

I've built a FULLTEXT index and this works well, however I need to be able to search for special characters, for example email addresses if searching for the `@` character. Is there a way to achieve this efficiently using `MySQL`?

Comment: Are you using MyISAM or InnoDB storage engine? They are different on how they implement fulltext indexes.

Comment: I upgraded to `MySQL 5.6` in order to use InnoDB for FULLTEXT indexes, so I don't have to create another MyISAM table for this. If it is required - I can use MyISAM as well.

Comment: Does this work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/8961228/1129642

Comment: If not, there is a special way to include additional charaters to be considered part of words in fulltext index.

Comment: Searching for the entire email address works even without using the quotes, I guess it is interpreted as 2 or 3 words therefore it matches easily. The problem is that we have to search for the "@" itself so I can find companies that listed their email address in the title or description field.

Comment: IMHO fulltext index is just for searching for words, not arbitrary chars at arbitrary positions... Maybe you will need to use `LIKE` for that.

Comment: It's totally inefficient to use `LIKE '%@%'` on a table with several thousands of rows :)

Comment: Or not. It seems to be pretty fast! O_o

Comment: OK, here's the thing: `LIKE '%@%'` rans pretty fast on my 19K rows (0.09). It takes 2 seconds to run on a table with 2M rows though. I guess I'll use the `LIKE` operator in my particular case, but I'll leave the question open for the 2M rows case.